# Returning null value from getUserid function

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's some piece of my code:

```
static Future<String> getUserId() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString(keyUserID) ?? null;
}
```

I'd like to return null if there's no userId, but the error i get is:

> A value of type 'String?' can't be returned from the method 'getUserId' because it has a return type of 'Future'.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This line of your code says that it can return either a string or null:

```
return prefs.getString(keyUserID) ?? null;
```

But if we then look at the declaration of the function, it says that it will return a `Future<String>`:

```
static Future<String> getUserId() async {
```

This means it says that it will always return a string at some point (or it will fail), but it won't return `null`.

These two parts don't match up, so that's why you get an error.

---

The solution is to say that the function returns either a string or null in the future, by changing `Future<String>` to `Future<String?>`:

```
static Future<String?> getUserId() async {
```

Since the declaration of the function and the `return` statement now agree on the type, the code will compile.